# Ubuntu 10.x Server on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2008-r2

How to run Ubuntu 10.x Server on Windows Server 2008 R2? Maybe virtual box? Any working links, tutorials, your experience will be nice!

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use Microsoft's hypervisor in that case - some basic information can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-faq.aspx). Slightly more detailed information on actually installing hyper-v and creating a virtual machine [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732470(WS.10).aspx).

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: as additional information it will be nice to see good tutorial about hyper-v and Ubuntu Server;)

Comment: @Edward83: This looks like a good blog post that details someone's direct experience http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2009/10/installing-ubuntu-on-hyper-v.html.

Comment: @Edward83: Also check out this article, it talks about needing to use a "Legacy Network Adapter" when configuring the Hyper-V VM virtual resources.   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-10-4-in-hyper-v.aspx